# How can I mock window.screen.width property?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have this condition in my component.

```
{window.screen.width > 1000 && (
            <WebFeatures
              scrolling={this.handleScrollToStats}
              ref_var={this.statsRef}
              ref_app={this.myRef}
              ref_reimburse={this.reimburse}
              ref_expense={this.expense}
            />``
          )}
```

How can I test this condition ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `spyOn` on `window.secreen.width` and return the value you need for you test:

```
jest.spyOn(window.screen, "width", "get").mockReturnValue(WIDTH);
```

Your tests will then look like:

```
it("Should NOT render WebFeatures in small screen", () => {
  jest.spyOn(window.screen, "width", "get").mockReturnValue(1000);
  const wrapper = mount(<YourComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.find("WebFeatures").exists()).toBe(false);
});

it("Should render WebFeatures in large screen", () => {
  jest.spyOn(window.screen, "width", "get").mockReturnValue(1001);
  const wrapper = mount(<YourComponent />);
  expect(wrapper.find("WebFeatures").exists()).toBe(true);
});
```